# Не выводится имя из метода __init__

Tags: python

Недавно начал изучать программирование, на данный момент читаю про классы и метод **init**, написал код, но почему то в нем не выводится имя и не программа не воспринимает текст (выдает ошибку). Прошу описать подробно в чем моя ошибка.

```
name = ""
age = ""
number = ""
select = ""


input("Введите ваше имя: ") == name
input("Введите ваш возраст: ") == age
input("Введите ваш номер: ") == number

class User():
    def __init__(self, name, age, number):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.number = number
    def hello(self):
        print(f"Здравствуйте, {user.name}, вы успешно вошли в базу.")
    def search_age(self):
        print(f"При запросе вашего возраста дало результат: {user.age}")
    def search_number(self):
        print(f"При запросе вашего номера дало результат: {user.number}")

user = User(name, age, number)

user.hello()
print()
print()
print()

default = True

while default:
    user = User(name, age, number)
    print(f"{user.name}, введите пожалуйста действие: Name, Age, Number")
    print("Для выхода введите: Exit")
    input("Действие: ") == select
    if select == "Name":
        print(f"Ваше имя: {user.name}.")
        print()
    elif select == "Age":
        user.search_age()
        print()
    elif select == "Number":
        user.search_number()
        print()
    elif select == "Exit":
        print("Выход...")
        default = False
    else: print("Вы что-то неправильно ввели...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ты неправильно записываешь результат в переменные.

````
age = ""
number = ""
select = ""


name = input("Введите ваше имя: ")
age = input("Введите ваш возраст: ")
number = input("Введите ваш номер: ")

class User():
    def __init__(self, name, age, number):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.number = number
    def hello(self):
        print(f"Здравствуйте, {user.name}, вы успешно вошли в базу.")
    def search_age(self):
        print(f"При запросе вашего возраста дало результат: {user.age}")
    def search_number(self):
        print(f"При запросе вашего номера дало результат: {user.number}")

user = User(name, age, number)

user.hello()
print()
print()
print()

default = True

while default:
    user = User(name, age, number)
    print(f"{user.name}, введите пожалуйста действие: Name, Age, Number")
    print("Для выхода введите: Exit")
    select = input("Действие: ")
    if select == "Name":
        print(f"Ваше имя: {user.name}.")
        print()
    elif select == "Age":
        user.search_age()
        print()
    elif select == "Number":
        user.search_number()
        print()
    elif select == "Exit":
        print("Выход...")
        default = False
    else: print("Вы что-то неправильно ввели...")```
````

Answer (score 0):

В итоге не заметил ответа и сам успел разобраться, но всё равно большое спасибо. Вот как выглядит теперь мой код:

```
print("Введите ваше имя: ")
name = input()
print("Введите ваш возраст: ")
age = input()
print("Введите ваш номер: ")
number = input

class User():
    def __init__(self, name, age, number):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.number = number
    def hello(self):
        print(f"Здравствуйте, {user.name}, вы успешно вошли в базу.")
    def search_age(self):
        print(f"При запросе вашего возраста дало результат: {user.age}")
    def search_number(self):
        print(f"При запросе вашего номера дало результат: {user.number}")

user = User(name, age, number)

user.hello()
print()
print()
print()

default = True

while default:
    user = User(name, age, number)
    print(f"{user.name}, введите пожалуйста действие: Name, Age, Number")
    print("Для выхода введите: Exit")
    select = input()
    if select == 'Name':
        print(f"Ваше имя: {user.name}.")
        print()
    elif select == 'Age':
        user.search_age()
        print()
    elif select == 'Number':
        user.search_number()
        print()
    elif select == 'Exit':
        print("Выход...")
        default = False
    else: print("Вы что-то неправильно ввели... \n")
```